# Why use `reduceRight` in a JavaScript compose function instead of the normal `reduce` function, and what are the benefits of doing so?

Tags: javascript

```
const square = (x) => {
  return x * x;
};
const double = (x) => {
  return x * 2;
};

function composeWithReduceRight(...fns) {
  return function (x) {
    return fns.reduceRight((acc, fn) => fn(acc), x);
  };
}

function composeWithReduce(...fns) {
  return function (x) {
    return fns.reduce((acc, fn) => fn(acc), x);
  };
}

composeWithReduceRight(square, double) // 16
composeWithReduce(double,square) // 16
```

It seems to work correctly if I change the order of arguments. I've noticed that many example codes use `reduceRight`, but I'm not entirely sure why it's necessary. Can someone explain its significance?

Comment: Pretty sure it's just a shortcut for `.reverse().reduce()`. Oh, and some kinds of operations are dependent on order, such as transforms.

Comment: Possibly. Except, these days, we also have [`.toReversed()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/toReversed). I don't really have a good reason for having `.reduceRight`, myself, but implementing such a thing is trivial and maybe makes things better with minimal impact, so... why not?

Comment: @Ouroborus definitely not "just a shortcut" 1. `.reverse()` modifies the input 2. `.reverse().reduce()` would iterate twice 3. the indexes used in the callback will be the opposite ones.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because [function composition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_composition) naturally is right-to-left:

```
compose(double, square)(2)
==      double( square( 2 ) )

compose(square, double)(2)
==      square( double( 2 ) )
```